# cannot download files from custom folder in nestjs app

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

In my nestjs application am uploading files to custom folder "Uploads". But am getting error when am trying to access the file

when I call this URL :

```
 http://localhost:3000/Uploads/file.png

 {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET 
 /Uploads/file.png","error":"Not Found"}
```

But when I upload files to public folder am able to download it as:-

```
http://localhost:3000/file.png
```

How to download the files from Uploads folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your main.ts

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {
    prefix: '/Uploads/',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this will work only if the same file which has been uploaded to Uploads folder exist in public folder.

I need to access the the files uploaded to Uploads folder separately independent to public folder

Comment: Also some folder levels may be there in Uploads folder like, Uploads/custon-id-eg:-44555gg4fddf/1/folder_name/file.pdf

Comment: Edit for first comment:- but this is still loading files from public folder only not from Uploads (cannot edit comment)